# Java Card program using GPJ

Tags: javacard

So I was tasked to create a java client to communicate with java card.

Right now I can authenticate, write and read data using javax.smartcardio but having a bit of trouble trying to upload cap file and install it.
So after googling around, I found that I can use gpj as a library and use it in my java application to upload and install the cap file.

The problem is I can't find any documentation for gpj and I can't understand the code without one.
Here's one that I have trouble to understand `public void installAndMakeSelecatable(AID paramAID1, AID paramAID2, AID paramAID3, byte paramByte, byte[] paramArrayOfByte1, byte[] paramArrayOfByte2)`

Even when I look on the other part of the code, I can't find out the last parameter since all that use these method will pass null.

So if anyone know where can I find the documentation, I would be really glad. Or better yet, another library that can upload cap file and have some documentation with it.

so far, I've found gpj,jpcsc,jcManager and opal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems that I'm not a clever guy.

For future reference, you can find out what to pass to what method by looking through the main method of the Global Platform Services class. For parameter that you are not sure what to pass, just use null.